# mask my proxy so servers can't detect I am using proxy

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy

I am using http proxy in my python webbrowser. In my php script on server side I am still able to detect requests go through proxy. How can I mask it so other servers are not able to find out I am using http proxy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your proxy so it does not add the `X-Forwarded-For` header identifying the request as coming from a proxy.

If you don't control the proxy, you are SOL.

You could also, conceivably, use a SOCKS proxy instead of an HTTP one.